# What kind of lense do you need to use to get a picture of the sun that looks like this?

Tags: optics, lenses

This is a picture of the sun from the moon.

[image]

When I look at the sun with my eyes, I see something like this: [image]

But the above picture is perfectly round, which makes me think it has to do with the shape of the lenses/aperture, but if the shape of the lenses/aperture is causing this, I would like to see a picture taken on earth were the sun appears to be round and gives completely round sun rays.

When we take a picture of the sun from earth we see a similar picture as the one taken from the ISS, so I am guessing with a similar lens we can take a picture of the sun that appears to be completely round, even when taken from the earth. What kind of lenses/aperture are needed to produce the same picture?

[image]

Comment: May be better suited to https://photo.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: It's not really the lense that causes the spikes, but the mainly apperture through which the light travels, and that could be on topic here if asked correctly.

Comment: The first picture is a classic example of [_lens flare_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare) which, like Grapefruit said above, is more of a photography topic than a physics topic.